# How to cast linq query to an object IEnumerable module class type?

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I am using a linq query like below

```
var result = from posts in repository.JobPosts
                      orderby posts.PostDate descending
                       select posts;
```

I have a property class JobPost with the same column names and number of columns just like the Table from the query above. I created another module class of with a method of the type JobPost class like below

```
 public class MainPageModel
 {
        public IEnumerable<JobPost> jobPost { get; set; }
        public SearchTerms searchTerms { get; set; }
 }
```

My JobPost is another module/propery class with equal rows as the JobPosts table above. I am trying to cast my query result to my module directly considering both are of the same columns. I modified my query to

```
IEnumerable<JobPost> res =(IEnumerable<JobPost>)
                           (from posts in repository.JobPosts
                            orderby posts.PostDate descending
                            select posts) ;
```

My linq above returned the row quesry

```
SELECT 
    *
    FROM [dbo].[JobPosts] AS [Extent1]
    ORDER BY [Extent1].[Id] ASC
```

Is there any way i can return the result of my query (that is the rows) and cast them to my IEnumerable class considering they are of equal columns.

Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT**

I plan to populate my class with the resulting query like below.

```
 MainPageModel model = new MainPageModel
        {
            jobPost = res,
            searchTerms = search
        };
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just because they have the same properties, it does not mean you can cast from one to the other. At very least you must map these properties explicitly:

```
IEnumerable<JobPost> res =(IEnumerable<JobPost>)
                       (from posts in repository.JobPosts
                        orderby posts.PostDate descending
                        select new JobPost{
                           Field1 = posts.Field1,
                           Field2 = posts.Field2,
                        }) ;
```

You may like to look at [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/) too, as it simplifies (with some overhead!) this sort of task

Comment: from your example can i map the whole column in the query explicitly ? Will that work ? Please see my update on how i plan to map it before. For the mean time wil try ur solu. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can query database directly using ExecuteQuery:

```
IEnumerable<JobPost> res = repository.ExecuteQuery<JobPost>("SELECT * FROM JobPosts ORDER BY Id");
```